# Nullable method-chaining with ?-Operator

Tags: vb.net, nullable, method-chaining

I thought I can chain methods/properties on Nullable Types using the ?-Operator like so

```
Dim foo As SomeObject? = New SomeObject()
Dim bar As SomeObject? = Nothing
foo?.SomeProperty 'Returns a value
bar?.someProperty 'Returns Nothing
```

However, given the following special example

```
Structure Foo
  Public Sub New(bar As Integer)
    Me.Bar = bar
  End Sub
  Property Bar() As Integer
  Public Shared Operator +(f1 As Foo, f2 As Foo) As Foo
    Return New Foo(f1.Bar + f2.Bar)
  End Operator
End Structure
```

I get an error after performing the following Operation

```
Dim baz1 As Foo? = New Foo(13)
Dim baz2 As Foo? = New Foo(37)
Dim baz3 = baz1 + baz2
baz3?.Bar 'error BC36637: The '?' character cannot be used here
```

Why is that so and more important how can I achieve the behaviour shown in my first example at the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Main issue after testing:**

I copied your exact code into VS2015 and tested it. The issue is because you are attempting to call a property, but are not doing anything with it.

You cannot just call a property. You either need to write to it or read from it. The below works just fine.

```
Dim baz1 As Foo? = New Foo(13)
Dim baz2 As Foo? = New Foo(37)
Dim baz3 = baz1 + baz2

Dim fooBar = baz3?.Bar
```

If I actually add a method, it too will work:

```
Dim baz1 As Foo? = New Foo(13)
Dim baz2 As Foo? = New Foo(37)
Dim baz3 = baz1 + baz2
baz3?.FooBar()
```

The actual error I got with your code was:

> BC30545: Property access must assign to the property or use its value.

**Old thought:**

The issue is with your Operator `+` overload. You returned a standard struct instance. This is not nullable. Therefore, you cannot use the `?` operator as it will never be null and isn't nullable.

```
Public Shared Operator +(f1 As Foo, f2 As Foo) As Foo
    Return New Foo(f1.Bar + f2.Bar)
End Operator
```

You may be able to get it to work (untested) by changing your declaration to:

```
Dim baz3 As Foo? = baz1 + baz2
```

But even then that may not work because `baz1+baz2` currently will also never be null.

Comment: a quick type check using `TypeOf(baz3) ...` reveals `Foo?` as the actual type and as such the chaining with the ?-character should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: @no_mindset I don't see that because the code you showed listed as the return for your operator overload was `As Foo`. It would need to be `As Foo?` if you wanted it to return a nullable type. It may work at runtime, but you are getting an error at compile time.

Comment: even if i declare the return type of the Operator overload `As Foo?` the same error occurs; type of `bar3` is still `Foo?`

Comment: @no_mindset updated my answer after actually testing your code.

Comment: +1 ty, i accepted the answer because i believe you're right - but even assigning the property or calling an equivalent method does result in the error for me, but i heavily assume i have to blame my compiler for not being the latest version to support the ?-character in that place. could you please confirm your vbc.exe version for me? mine is 14.6.1586

Comment: @no_mindset That's the version I have in my .NET folder, but I don't believe that is what Visual Studio is running as you still need newer version of VS in order to use newer syntactic sugar. For instance VS2013 doesn't support C#6 even though I also have VS2015 installed.

Comment: That must be the problem as I have no VS2015 installed currently. Thank you very much!